# "Property does not exist on type" error upon passing data from parent to child using @input in Angular

Tags: angular

```
**Parent component ts**
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Recipe } from './recipe.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipe-list',
  templateUrl: './recipe-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipe-list.component.css']
})
 recipes: Recipe[] = [
    new Recipe('A Test Recipe', 'This is simply a test', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Recipe_logo.jpeg'),
    new Recipe('Another Test Recipe', 'This is simply a test', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Recipe_logo.jpeg')
  ];

**parent component html**
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <app-recipe-item *ngFor="let recipeEl of Recipes" 
[RecipesList]="recipeEl"></app-recipe-item>
    </div>
</div>

**child-component ts **
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Recipe } from '../recipe.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipe-item',
  templateUrl: './recipe-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipe-item.component.css']
})
export class RecipeItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() RecipesList: Recipe;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}

**child-component -html**
<div class="media border p-3 bg-info rounded">
    <div class="media-body">
        <h5 class="mt-0 mb-1">{{ recipeEl.name }}</h5>
        {{ recipeEl.description }}
    </div>
    <img src="{{ recipeEl.imagePath }}" class="ml-3 img-responsiv rounded" alt="..." style="max-height: 80px;" />
</div>
```

When I am trying to pass data from parent to child component using @input decorator I am getting error

> error TS2339: Property 'recipeEl' does not exist on type
> 'RecipeItemComponent'.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> error TS2339: Property 'recipeEl' does not exist on type 'RecipeItemComponent'
> Well, it doesn't. The input, and the property, on the child component, is named `RecipesList`:

```
export class RecipeItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() RecipesList: Recipe;
```

Which is by the way bad name, as it suggests a list, not a single item. Best rename the input to, simply, `recipe`, and stick to it:

```
<app-recipe-item *ngFor="let recipeEl of Recipes" [recipe]="recipeEl"></app-recipe-item>
```

```
export class RecipeItemComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() recipe: Recipe;
```

```
    <div class="media-body">
        <h5 class="mt-0 mb-1">{{ recipe.name }}</h5>
        {{ recipe.description }}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change a bit:
**parent component html**
typo is 'recipes'

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let recipeEl of recipes">
         <app-recipe-item  
          [RecipesList]="recipeEl"></app-recipe-item>
         </ng-container>
    </div>
</div>
```